# How to click a specific button in all tab of every window

Tags: javascript, applescript

I open a webpage in 5 different windows and want to click same button in all tabs of every window
I  write this script, its working for one window only but nothing happen in remaining 4 windows

```
tell application "Safari"
  repeat with t in tabs of windows

    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('submitButton')[7].click();" in document 1
  end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `document 1` with `t`

```
tell application "Safari"
    repeat with t in tabs of windows
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('submitButton')[7].click();" in t
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: error "Safari got an error: Can’t make item 1 of every tab of every window into type integer." number -1700 from item 1 of every tab of every window to integer

Comment: i am getting this error after replacing 1 with t ..any idea?

Comment: Please do exactly what I suggested. it's not `document t` it's just `t`